# Is there an exporter plugin for Selenium IDE that puts out Remote::Driver Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

So far I have only seen the exporter that gives us `Test::WWW::Selenium` scripts.

I fear this might not be the right place to ask; if that's true please point me in the right direction.  To calibrate your snark filters, yes, I have tried Google.

Comment: So what did you find when you tried Google?

Comment: There are lots of links for the exporter addon to the IDE that creates a script utilizing `Test::WWW::Selenium`.  I found there is this article (http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2011/07/08/selenium-ide-and-selenium-2-webdriver/) from Summer 2011 stating that if Perl support for WebDriver is taken up, an exporter would be released.  I've left a comment there, and then I came here to check with this community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code of the mentioned perl module, there is an example IDE formatter code: https://github.com/teodesian/Selenium-Remote-Driver/blob/v.138/ide-plugin.js

Comment: Thanks.  In the two years since I posted this all the `Test::WWW::Selenium` code has been moved under `Selenium::Remote::Driver` and the world makes sense again.

Answer (score 0):

If you had searched on google, what you typed on SO, you would find this as your first result
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-perl-formatter/

Comment: As I mentioned, the tool you linked exports a script that uses `Test::WWW::Selenium`'.  I'm really wondering if a similar tool exists that exports a script utilizing `Remote::Driver`.